# Filter all the primes from an array of integers

Tags: python

Given an array of integers how do I return a new array containing all of the primes in descending order?

```
def returnPrime (list):
```

Example: When calling the function as follows:

```
returnPrime ((10,21,3,8,9,11,44,62,100,19))
```

It should return

```
[19,11,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPrime(n): 
    if n <= 1: return False
    for i in range(2, n): 
        if n % i == 0: 
            return False; 
  
    return True

def returnPrime(list):
    primes = []
    for l in list:
       for p in l:
           if isPrime(p):
              primes += p
    return primes
```

if you want a faster version, you have to generate prime numbers with Eratosthenes sieve and save them, then checking will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def return_primes(arr):
    return list(filter(lambda x : is_prime(x), arr))

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

print(return_primes([10,21,3,8,9,11,44,62,100,19]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the isPrime() function inside your prime filtering function:

```
def getPrimes(A):
    def isPrime(N): return all(N%d for d in (2,*range(3,int(N**0.5)+1,2)))
    return sorted(filter(isPrime,A),reverse=True)
```

output:

```
r = getPrimes([10,21,3,8,9,11,44,62,100,19])

print(r)
# [19, 11, 3]
```

In most cases this is faster than using the sieve of Eratosthenes.  The Sieve does provide better performance for large lists of numbers that are relatively close to each other (e.g. `[100+i*7+2 for i in range(100)]`).

Here is an example of a function that uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes if you want to play with it and see the difference:

```
def getPrimes2(A):
    maxA = max(A)
    isPrime = [False]*2+[True]*(maxA-1)        # sieve bits covering A
    for n in (2,*range(3,maxA+1,2)):           # run through divisors
        if not isPrime[n]: continue
        isPrime[n*n::n] = [False]*len(isPrime[n*n::n]) # flag non-primes
    primes = [a for a in A if isPrime[a]]      # filter A on primes
    return sorted(primes,reverse=True)         # return sorted result
```

If you know the maximum value that the list can contain and the function is going to be called multiple times, the overall performance can be improved by preparing the isPrime list ahead of time in a global variable.  If you exclude the time needed to setup the isPrime list, the performance of each call to getPrimes() will be orders of magnitude faster:

```
maxPrime = 1000000                             # largest number in lists
isPrime = [False]*2+[True]*(maxPrime-1)        # sieve bits covering A
for n in (2,*range(3,maxPrime+1,2)):           # run through divisors
    if not isPrime[n]: continue
    isPrime[n*n::n] = [False]*len(isPrime[n*n::n]) # flag non-primes

def getPrimes(A):
    return sorted((a for a in A if isPrime[a]),reverse=True)
```